# Extracting specific data from json using jquery

Tags: json, jquery

From the following json snippet:

```
cbfunc22({
  query: {
    count: 2,
      created: "2012-06-18T11:18:15Z",
      lang: "en-US",
      results: {
        tbody: [{
            tr: [{
                class: "day",
                td: [{
                    class: "dayname",
                    p: "Monday"
                  },
                  {
                    class: "weather",
                    p: "Sunny Intervals"
                  },
```

I can extract `Monday` using jQuery as follows:

`data.query.results.tbody[0].tr[0].td[0].p`

How do I extract `Sunny Intervals` ?

Comment: `data.query.results.tbody[0].tr[0].td[1].p` http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/RYdvs/

Comment: That's not JSON. (Given the function syntax at the beginning is it perhaps the return of a jsonp call?). You need to be careful about object literals that have unquoted property names if you're going to include names ("class") that are JS reserved words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.query.results.tbody[0].tr[0].td[1].p
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tbody > tr > td > p:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
data.query.results.tbody[0].tr[0].td[1].p
```

If you indent your code correctly the solution is more apparent:

```
cbfunc22(
{
    query: {
        count: 2,
        created: "2012-06-18T11:18:15Z",
        lang: "en-US",
        results: {
            tbody: [
                    {
                        tr: [
                                {
                                    class: "day",
                                    td: [
                                         {
                                               class: "dayname",
                                           p: "Monday"
                                         },
                                         {
                                           class: "weather",
                                           p: "Sunny Intervals"
                                         },
```

Answer (score 0):

`td` is an array, so index 0 gives the first element, index 1 gives the second:

```
data.query.results.tbody[0].tr[0].td[1].p
```

and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

`td[0]` is for **Monday** so `td[1]` is for **Sunny Intervals** and so on

so **Sunny Intervals** can be extracted by,

```
data.query.results.tbody[0].tr[0].td[1].p
```